# Storing nuget packages in alternate location on build server

Tags: .net, msbuild, nuget

When developing locally I have my Nuget packages installed in the default location (\packages within solution folder).

I want have a different folder on my build server that acts as the repository path where I can download packages too, effectively giving me a local cache of packages which will persist across builds, not requiring all packages to be downloaded fresh every time build.

On the CI server I drop a nuget.config file into the solution directory which specifies the location of the new packages folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <!-- Specify repository path -->
    <add key="repositorypath" value="x:\nugetPackages" />
  </config>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
</configuration>
```

This part works fine and downloads packages to x:\nugetPackages\ but when I try to build the solution I get exceptions as the dlls are not found. This makes sense as the hintPath for the references is "..\packages\lib\lib.dll" whereas I want it to be on a different drive completely.

My main msbuild task is just building the Solution file. To get this to work I've tried various options in my msbuild script, from:

- Specifying AssemblySearchPaths in BeforeResolveReferences task (as per http://www.beefycode.com/post/resolving-binary-references-in-msbuild.aspx)
- Manually specifying AdditionalLibPaths and/or AssemblySearchPaths as a parameter when building the project.
- Specifying another "activePackageSource" element in the nuget.config file.

All of the above result in lots of warnings similar to: `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpRequestMessage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I've managed to get it to work by altering the MSBuild script to:

1. Restore nuget packages to 'cache' folder (e.g. x:\nugetPackages).
2. Copy these packages over to the default location (..\packages).
3. Build solution.

This seems to be an overly long winded way of dealing with this, am I missing something obvious?  I've read a few blog posts where people are using XSLT to rewrite the 'hintPath' element for all project files in the solution - surely there's a better way of doing this?

Comment: You know that NuGet has a default cache, right? %localappdata%\NuGet\Cache Why not use that as your first entry in the packagesources list?

Comment: Feel like a fool now, knew I was missing something. Thanks, that looks like it'll work great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NuGet has a built-in local cache at `%localappdata%\NuGet\Cache` which you could use as a package source in your nuget.config.

NuGet will restore packages from packagesources in the order defined in your config and stop scanning at its first hit. (activepackagesource should be the aggregate 'All' feed)

Answer (score 7):

I see there is some confusion between 2 concepts in nuget.

- Package Source: This is where packages are downloaded **from** at install/restore (on your build server this means on restore time)
- Package repository: this is where packages are downloaded **to**

If you want to save disk space on your build server you can set up a common package repository which all your projects can reference. One big annoyance with this is (as you noticed) the hintpaths in Visual Studio. If you want to use a common package repo everybody needs to use this approach. (or you can can create a symlink in your solution folder to the common package repository with mklink, this gives a common package repo without breaking the hintpaths)

An example:

```
c:\packages\ --> our shared package repository
c:\mySolutions\solution1
c:\mySolutions\solution1\packages --> symlink to c:\packages
c:\mySolutions\solution2
c:\mySolutions\solution2\packages --> symlink to c:\packages
```

The symlink can be created with the command:

```
cd c:\mySolutions\solution1
mklink /D packages c:\packages
```

If you want to prevent a download from the package source you can rely on the default caching from Nuget. (Note: that last time I checked this was still capped at 200 individual packages.)
When you are using the shared package repository the `nuget restore` command will see the packages as already installed and bypass the download as well.

Comment: Nice. Have you seen any noticeable speed improvement when using TFS build server?

Comment: Never checked. Since we have 800+ solutions we were mainly looking for saving disk space.

Comment: This. So much this. I made the `mklink /J packages e:\binaries\NuGet` a build step before MSBuild does its thing. This works insofar as the nuget packages are getting downloaded there now, but for some reason, MSBuild still doesn't see them, despite the hint paths resolving correctly from the project file to the packages directory.

Comment: Could it be related to the fact that you create a junction point instead of a symlink. (/J instead of /D)