# Configure TFS2015 build to understand my custom nuget repository location

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015, nuget, tfsbuild

I've been fiddling with the TFS2015 task based build system for a few days now. The problem I keep on running into is the following:

I am trying to use nuget packages for my external references in my projects. These exernal references are actually not 3rd party libraries but simply other (shared) libraries of our company. I'm able to restore the packages in a task, but I can't figure out how i can make the "Visual studio Build" understand where to find the restored packages. It uses the hintpath in the project file to determine the location of the external libraries to include. However, these paths (which are used locally for development) don't match the paths used on the build server. I can add a referencepath to the msbuild parameters, but this path isn't searched recursively, and the nuget package restore restores packages including the entire folder structure of the package.

My question is. Is there a proper way to make the "Visual Studio build" step understand the location of my packages without changing the hintpath in the project file. If not, what is the normal way to go here. Should I move away from nuget altogether because our references are not actually 3rd party libraries, and if so, what is the alternative way of resolving the references (without adding the binaries to source control)

My question seems to be related to [Storing nuget packages in alternate location on build server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24617112), however he seems to have fixed it using a copy to the location that is specified in the hintpath of the references, which is not an option for me. It seems to me there should be an easy way I'm not seeing to be able to point msbuild to the correct location for the libraries.

Comment: Does the msbuild step error out?  We also use the new scripted build system.  We add a NuGet Installer build step before our MSBuild step, and it seems to "just work". Are you on the online TFS (VSTS) or on-premise?

Comment: We use on-premise tfs. msbuild can simply not find the references, since it looks for the references in the location specified in the hintpath in the project file. However, this location differs from the location of the references on the build server.

I got the nuget restore to work when i forced the dll's to be in the same location as they are on the development machines. This is probably the reason in works for you too. However, in our scenario the locations differ

Comment: shouldnt dll be in Version control path to custom assemblies. Atleast on older TFS

Comment: That's the whole point of what I'm trying to avoid. I already got it working without having the dll's in version control, however not with the assemblies in a different location.

Answer (score 0):

After the task restoring packages, you can add task "Copy Files" to copy the packages to the location "..\packages\lib\lib.dll"

[image]

Comment: Yes i believe this would work. However I find it hard to believe this is the best way to do this. Are we trying to do such a weird thing? I would like to believe more companies struggle with these kind of issues

Comment: After some research, this is not going to work. We use a single repository on the build server for all packages. A copy action would copy ALL dll's for ALL packages to the root of the repository every time a build is run. This is of course a performance hit, but even more important: the respository can contain different versions of the same reference, which would overwrite eachother in the root folder.

Comment: Copy Files can only copy files, you don't need to copy all dlls, but copy the dll you need.

Comment: I know, but this would mean a lot of work in maintaining the build tasks. Every time a references is added/removed we'll have to update the build process

Comment: You can modify Repository Path in NuGet Configuration Settings to install the NuGet packages in the specified folder, instead of the default "$(Solutiondir)\Packages" folder. Check: https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file